# Android Collection Widget not working on KitKat

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a collection widget with a `ListView` on Android and it works fine for versions above 19. Nevertheless, with KitKat (which is the minimum supported version in our app) it doesn't work.

I can see the widget -there's an ImageView and a FrameLayout with another ImageView and an `animated-rotate` for when the widget updates- but it has an empty ListView and the clicks on the aforementioned ImageView doesn't work.

Is there anything special to do so the widget runs on KitKat? Am I missing something?

I realised that the setRemoteAdapter works, and even the `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` gets called, but it's just not reflecting the changes in the screen, nor are the click events working on static views -not the `ListView` I'm using, which doesn't even show items.

This is the way I'm doing it:

```
private fun buildWidget(appWidgetIds: IntArray, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, context: Context) {
val remoteViews = getRemoveViews(context)

    // Set up the intent that starts the AppWidgetService, which will provide the views for this collection.
    for (i in appWidgetIds.iterator()) {
        val intent = Intent(context, AppWidgetService::class.java)

        // Add the app widget ID to the intent extras.
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, i)
        intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
        intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

        // Check for a valid session in order to either show the positions list or a view to ask the user to log in
        if (userSession.hasValidSession()) {
            // Set up the RemoteViews object to use a RemoteViews adapter. This adapter connects to a RemoteViewsService  through the specified intent. This is how you populate the data.
            remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.app_widget_portfolio_list, intent)

            // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items. It should be in the same layout used to instantiate the RemoteViews object above.
            remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.app_widget_portfolio_list, R.id.app_widget_empty_view)
            setOpenAppOnClickPendingIntent(context, remoteViews, R.id.app_widget_empty_view)
            // Bind a click listener template for the contents of the weather list.  Note that we
            // need to update the intent's data if we set an extra, since the extras will be
            // ignored otherwise.
            val onClickIntent = Intent(ACTION_LIST_ITEM_CLICK, null, context, AppWidget::class.java)
            val onClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, number++, onClickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.app_widget_portfolio_list, onClickPendingIntent)

            val refreshPositionsIntent = Intent(ACTION_REFRESH, null, context, AppWidget::class.java)
            refreshPositionsIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, i)
            val refreshPositionsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, refreshPositionsIntent, 0)
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_widget_refresh_button, refreshPositionsPendingIntent)

setOpenAppOnClickPendingIntent(context, remoteViews, R.id.app_widget_logo)
            appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(i, remoteViews)
}

private fun setOpenAppOnClickPendingIntent(context: Context, remoteViews: RemoteViews, @IdRes viewId: Int) {
        val openAppIntent = MainActivity.newNavigateIntent(context, AppUrl.getHomeUrl())
        val loginPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, loginPendingIntent)
    }
```

I have tried so far to change the `requestCode` of the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and use random numbers, but still, it doesn't work. I also tried `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, remoteViews)` instead of `appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(i, remoteViews)` but still, no luck.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: OK, I got the problem now: in `onUpdate` I was calling `appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(i, remoteViews)` instead of `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, remoteViews)`, which according to documentation: `Perform an incremental update or command on the widget specified by appWidgetId.

This update differs from updateAppWidget(int, RemoteViews) in that the RemoteViews object which is passed is understood to be an incomplete representation of the widget, and hence is not cached by the AppWidgetService.`